# wordpress login redirection loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have done a fresh wordpress installation inside a subdirectory. I've followed the official wordpress guide to give wordpress it's own directory, but now I have some problems to login. The problem is that I'm not able to login to the dashboard and every attempts will redirect me to the login sreen. How I can fix this?

I have this code inside my .htaccess root file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mynicewebsite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mynicewebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And this is the .htaccess file inside the directory where wordpress is installed

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change the line `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase mynicewebsite.com/wordpressdirectory` in the .htaccess of WordPress and the lime `RewriteBase /` too. Because when you use / you are send to the root of the url. For more informations you can read [this WordPress support page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/).